# finding larger number using dynamic memory allocation

Tags: c

Writing a program to find largest number using dynamic memory allocation. I have
    written the             following code, there is some problem in
    sorting part I am doing selectin sorting by    pointers . but
    sorting    is not not done    properly .....can we do selection
    sort by    pointers am I applying    right
    approach?

```
         #include<stdio.h>
         #include<stdlib.h>  
         main()
         {

            int i,j,n,temp;
            int *data;
            printf("enter total no of elements:");
            scanf("%d",&n);
            data=(int*)calloc(n,sizeof(int));
            printf("\n");
            for(i=0;i<n;i++)
            {
                         printf("enter number %d:",i+1);
                         scanf("%d",data+i);
            }
           for(i=0;i<n;i++)
           {
                   printf("%d\t",*(data+i));
            }
           printf("\n");
           for(i=0;i<n;i++)
           {
                   for(j=i+1;j<n;j++)
               {
                       if(*(data)>*(data+j))
                   {
                        temp=*(data);
                        *(data)=*(data+j);
                        *(data+j)=temp;
                    }
               }


            }
            for(i=0;i<n;i++)
            {
                 printf("%d\t",*(data+i));
            } 
            printf("largest element is %d\t",*(data+n-1));
         }
```

output:

```
         enter total no of elements:5

         enter number 1:2
         enter number 2:10
         enter number 3:12
         enter number 4:1
         enter number 5:0
         2  10  12  1   0   
         0  10  12  2
```

Comment: What output do you expect?

Answer (score 2):

You need little modification in your code

```
   for(i=0;i<n-1;i++) //change here
       {
               for(j=i+1;j<n;j++)
           {
                   if(*(data+i)>*(data+j)) //here
               {
                    temp=*(data+i);      //here
                    *(data+i)=*(data+j); //here
                    *(data+j)=temp;
                }
           }
```

You are always comparing first element(`*data`) with `*(data+j)`. You need to compare `*(data+i)` with `*(data+j)`

Comment: It's probably worth noting why you want to change the first line, too.
It's because on the last time through the loop, i is 1 less than n, which makes j equal to n. That's causing an out of bounds error, which is probably why you're losing the last number.

Comment: @JonahNelson changing that causes no effect.it just saves one iteration of outer for loop and why do we check two conditions. when we just need to check one.

Comment: I was using the assumption that he didn't post his whole code, since we don't know where his print code is for the sorted array. There's no guarantee that he's not using j somewhere without reinitializing it, and the way it is, the final iteration of the outer loop causes the inner test value to be evaluated once, even though the body is skipped, which sets j to one past the end of the array, and would potentially cause some uh...difficulty.

Comment: @JonahNelson OP posted full code. please check code once again.

Answer (score 1):

This section:

```
if(*(data)>*(data+j))
{
    temp=*(data);
    *(data)=*(data+j);
    *(data+j)=temp;
}
```

Is only considering the first element (`data[0]`) and element j (`data[j]`).

I think you really mean to consider `data[i]` vs. `data[j]`

---

**Questions to ask yourself**

- Why did I write the `for(i)` loop?
- Where is the variable `i` actually being used?

Answer (score 1):

This is because you are comparing it always with the first element. it should be

```
for(i=0;i<n;i++)
       {
               for(j=i+1;j<n;j++)
           {
                   if(*(data+i)>*(data+j))
               {
                    temp=*(data+i);
                    *(data+i)=*(data+j);
                    *(data+j)=temp;
                }
           }


        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Note that in C you can use `data[i]` instead of `*(data + i)`. This algorithm will find the **largest** (if your question assumed this) number. Let `data` be your array, `n` will be the size of your array, and `temp` will be the largest one.

```
temp = data[0];
for(i = 1; i < n; ++i)
{
    if (data[i] > temp)
        temp = data[i];
}
```

or definitely

```
i = 0;
temp = data[i++];
while(i < n)
{
    if (data[i] > temp)
        temp = data[i];
}
```

You had implemented the sorting algorithm. If you're just wanted to find the largest number, then use my snippet instead of your two nested for loops.

Answer (score 0):

```
       for(i=0;i<n;i++)
       {
               for(j=i+1;j<n;j++)
           {
                   if(*(data)>*(data+j))
               {
                    temp=*(data);
                    *(data)=*(data+j);
                    *(data+j)=temp;
                }
           }


        }
```

What have you achieved through the outer for loop that runs upto n-1 ?

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main()
{
    int i, num;
    float *data;
    printf("Enter total number of elements(1 to 100): ");
    scanf("%d", &num);
    // Allocates the memory for 'num' elements.
    data = (float*) calloc(num, sizeof(float));
    if(data == NULL)
    {
        printf("Error!!! memory not allocated.");
        exit(0);
    }
    printf("\n");
    // Stores the number entered by the user.
    for(i = 0; i < num; ++i)
    {
       printf("Enter Number %d: ", i + 1);
       scanf("%f", data + i);
    }
    // Loop to store largest number at address data
    for(i = 1; i < num; ++i)
    {
       // Change < to > if you want to find the smallest number
       if(*data < *(data + i))
           *data = *(data + i);
    }
    printf("Largest element = %.2f", *data);
    return 0;
}
```